# Can't retrieve xml information in Java

Tags: java, xml

i try to retrieve some informations from an xml file, but it returns me a null object. I use DOM to parse the file(see the code bellow). I need some help, because i don't know if it's my logic or my code which is bad. Thank you for your time !

```
public class ReadXMLFile {
private File fXmlFile;
private Document doc;
private Contact m_contact=null;

public ReadXMLFile(String name){
    try{
        m_contact = new Contact();
        fXmlFile = new File("/pathtofile/"+name+".xml"); //should be verified
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean readXml(String _id){
    try{
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        if(doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("listContact")){
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("contact");
            Node nNode;

              nNode = nList.item(Integer.parseInt(_id));
              if (nNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("contact")){
                  if(nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                      System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
                      Element eElement = (Element)nNode;//get element of node
                      m_contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(eElement.getAttribute("id")));
                      m_contact.setPhoneNumber(eElement.getAttribute("phoneNumber"));
                      m_contact.setName(eElement.getAttribute("name"));
                      m_contact.setFistName(eElement.getAttribute("firstName"));
                      return true;
                    }  
              }
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public Contact getM_contact() {
    if(m_contact!=null){
        return m_contact;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

This is my xml result :

```
<listContact>
  <contact id="0">
    <firstName>martin</firstName>
    <lastName>dupond</lastName>
    <phoneNumber>514</phoneNumber>
    <synchronize>false</synchronize>
  </contact>
</listContact>
```

output :

```
Contact{id=0, phoneNumber=, name=, fistName=, synchronize=false}
```

Comment: Which object is null?

Comment: Please edit your post and add a sample of the input XML you are reading.

Comment: Please post full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i tried it and it worked for me

```
Node nNode = nList.item(Integer.parseInt(temp));

    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("phoneNumber").item(0).getTextContent());

    }
return false;
....
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `getAttribute` on the `contact` element to retrieve values for `firstName` etc, but in your XML these are not attributes, but child elements.

If you were using JDOM API, you could simply use the `getChild(name)` method. In "standard" DOM API, you have to go through a few more hoops though, something like this:

```
  Element eElement = (Element)nNode;

  // only one first name element
  Element firstNameElem = eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0); 
  m_contact.setFistName(firstNameElem.getNodeValue());
```

Comment: I don't have this method with my Element object. I have getChildNodes but it isn't that.

Comment: Ah sorry, I assumed you used JDOM. In that case, you'll need to use `getElementsByTagName(name)` and process the resulting `NodeList`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for you help, i think that i'll try with JDOM. It's more simple.

Comment: As well you should give Jaxb a try. This is Javas standard xml to pojo mapper.